# Query in COGNOS (Report Studio)

Tags: sql, cognos, cognos-8

I have this follow query;
the objective is to filter this query by day.

I will use this same query, but now a month. How to do?

```
WITH DATAS(DATA_CALC) AS(

  SELECT DATE(#prompt('DataIni')#) AS DATA_CALC FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATA_CALC + 1 DAY FROM DATAS WHERE DATA_CALC < DATE(#prompt('DataFim')#)

)

/* ABERTOS */
SELECT COUNT(*) AS QUANTIDADE, 'ABERTOS' AS TIPO, 1 AS NUM_LINHA, DATE(TRUNC(SOL.DATA_ABERTURA_SOLICITACAO)) AS DATA
FROM VW_SOLICITACAO_DETALHE SOL
  INNER JOIN SOLICITACAO SOL_TAB ON (SOL_TAB.ID_SOLICITACAO = SOL.ID_SOLICITACAO)
WHERE SOL.COD_TIPO_SERVICO IN ('MC','OP','SA')
  AND SOL_TAB.ID_AREA_COLABORADOR IN (#promptmany('IDArea')#)
  AND TRUNC(SOL.DATA_ABERTURA_SOLICITACAO) >= to_date('2014-11-18','YYYY-MM-DD')
  AND TRUNC(SOL.DATA_ABERTURA_SOLICITACAO) <= #prompt('DataFim')#
  AND ('TODOS' IN (#promptmany('Sistema')#) OR SOL.COD_PRODUTO IN (#promptmany('Sistema')#))
  AND DSC_SITUACAO_SOLICITACAO NOT IN ('Desenvolvimento Cancelado')
  AND SOL.COD_SOLICITACAO NOT LIKE 'SA%'
GROUP BY TRUNC(SOL.DATA_ABERTURA_SOLICITACAO)
```

Comment: Where is your CTE used?Is the query below related?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: This first query named WITH DATAS(DATA_CALC)..is not used in the following query as far as I can see.What you can do is just change `SELECT DATA_CALC + 1 DAY` to `SELECT DATA_CALC + 1 MONTH`

Comment: I tried changing day per month, but without success.

the query still does the group by a day

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to [create a Time dimension](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21373148) that includes days and months.  This is not easy to plug into Dynamic SQL like you are using above, so you can instead try a work around.

A report studio work around would be to create year and month columns, and group on them:

For year:
extract(year, [datefieldhere])

For month:
extract(month, [datefieldhere])